# IOS CoreBluetooth Per/Centr cross connection

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth, core-bluetooth

is it possible to cross-connect the peripheral peripheral of device a with the central of device b and the peripheral of device b with the central of device a at the same time?
greets from Germany!

Comment: Yes, you can do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is forbidden according to the [Bluetooth Specification v5.2](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/bluetooth-core-specification/), Vol 6, PartB, Section 4.5 (Connection State):-

> "There shall be only one connection between two LE device addresses.
>   An initiator shall not send a connection request to an advertiser it
>   is already connected to. If an advertiser receives a connection
>   request from an initiator it is already connected to, it shall ignore
>   that request."

In other words, even if this is allowed by swift right now then it is preferable that you don't use this because it is against the spec and will probably be removed in the future.

Comment: thanks! I've tested it and can confirm that it indeed does not work and the central just refuses to connect. greets